# Vulkan MAILBOX present mode

Tags: graphics, c++, vulkan

Does Vulkan MAILBOX Present mode exist on the NVIDIA driver for linux?
Using latest proprietary driver 525.
Computer Alienware with RTX 3060

Comment: This isn't a Linux Q&A site, but a Ubuntu site, why ask here?  (SE *Unix & Linux* covers Linux).  Your question appears to be seeking off-topic opinions too.

Answer (score 0):

Download [Vulkan Hardware Capability Viewer](http://www.vulkan.gpuinfo.org/download.php) and go to Surface -> Present Modes.

You can also browse the [online database](http://www.vulkan.gpuinfo.org/listreports.php?platform=linux) and [based](http://www.vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=19206#presentmodes) on the 2 last [reports](http://www.vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=19371#presentmodes) for Linux, **it appears** as of today NVIDIA GeForce 3060 does NOT support Mailbox on Linux.

I can confirm GCN-based and RDNA-based AMD GPUs do support Mailbox (using RADV).